# Automatically order table by highest value in last column of table

Tags: jquery, html

I have been unable to find a way to do this. I need the table to automatically be arranged by the amount raised from high to low (descending order). I cannot access the HTML for the table directly, it is automatically generated. Please help.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>team name </td>
        <td>team capain</td>
        <td>amount raised</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>team 1</td>
        <td>captain1</td>
        <td>CAN$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>team 2</td>
        <td>captain2</td>
        <td>CAN$5.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>team 3</td>
        <td>captain3</td>
        <td>CAN$3.00</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>team 4</td>
        <td>captain4</td>
        <td>CAN$20.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [This link](http://blog.niklasottosson.com/?p=1914) might give the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You used the tag `jquery` so I'm going to assume that even though you can't edit the html, you can still modify the page with `js` somehow.

So if you want to use a jquery plugin, here is a good one: http://tablesorter.com/

However, if you want to use just plain vanilla `js` another good one I've seen is this: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

Here is a working example of the second option (which I recommend since it doesn't need `<thead>` tags like the jquery one: http://jsfiddle.net/g6XM7/

Comment: Hey Rocks25, can you provide the link to the working example you mentioned? Thank you so much!

Comment: This script is not working in the example you provided, if I choose the last column heading it either places the $0 amount at the top or the $5 amount at the top. It should be sorted largest amount to smallest.

Comment: I just noticed that. I'm not sure why. I think it's because it can't recognize it as a price due to the "CAN" in front of it. How are you getting the generated html? Are you loading it in from a web api into your own page?

Comment: It is pulled from a database, sorry I don't know much about that end of things. A team registers and is automatically added along with the amount donors give to that team.

Comment: Could we use a script to remove CAN from the string? Would that work?

Comment: Possibly. Do you have any control over how it's being pulled from the database? Is it through a php file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any control over that